# calculating mean and margin of error

Tags: probability, statistics

A 95% confidence interval for the mean is given by $(210.4, 213.2)$.
 Give the mean and margin of error of the sample.

The mean would just be $\frac{210.4 + 213.2}{2} = 211.8$.

But how would you get the margin of error? The sample isn't given to us. This is where I'm stuck.

Look up 95% on the table, and you get 1.960

so

$$1.960 * \frac{211.8}{\sqrt{n}}$$

That's if I am doing this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really much simpler than that. The margin of error is simply the radius of your confidence interval, or mathematically 
$$
\text{margin of error } = \frac{213.2-210.4}{2} = \frac{7}{5}
$$

In general for a confidence interval $(a,b)$, it is given by $\frac{b-a}{2}$.

Comment: I see now!  Thanks.

Comment: @KevinR. Make sure you are careful about the difference between _margin_ of error and _sample_ error. And you are welcome.

Comment: caveat: be aware that there are all sorts of assumptions built into this question and answer (e.g., that the confidence interval is symmetric about the mean). but this is probably overkill at an introductory level.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes, I made that assumption based on his attempt at an answer using the Normal distribution.